# Wrong timezone information with Java JodaTime

Tags: android, node.js, date, momentjs, jodatime

I am generating some UTC time on my backend and sending it to my Android application using websockets.

The problem is: when I display the date, it's behind by 3 hours which is because I am assuming my phone is in the +3 timezone.

Below is an extract from both the backend code and the Android code.

Backend code (that's how I am generating the UTC date using the moment library):

```
let d = moment.utc().toISOString();
```

In my Android Application this is how I am handling it:

```
String sendDate = "2017-04-19T15:41:36.758Z"; //this is an example server response
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
dtf.parseLocalDateTime(sendDate).toDate()
```

The issue is that the UTC date is not shown/converted properly to the timezone the phone is currently in so the date is always behind by 3 hours.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked the phone's default `TimeZone` (the result of `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`)?

Comment: And what's the ouput you're getting vs expected output?

Comment: Try `dtf.parseLocalDateTime(sendDate).toDate(DateTimeZone.UTC)` because I fear that `toDate()` without argument implicitly uses the system timezone (with data of Joda-Time). And your `LocalDateTime` is obviously based on UTC-input...

Comment: @MenoHochschild Just one little detail, `LocalDateTime.toDate` method takes a `java.util.TimeZone` as argument (according to [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDate-java.util.TimeZone-), for joda-time >= 2.3), so the call will be `dtf.parseLocalDateTime(sendDate).toDate(DateTimeZone.UTC.toTimeZone())`. But I'm not sure if that's what OP wants

Comment: @Hugo You are right, I have overlooked it and am surprised that Joda-Time really uses the old API at this place. And both methods in question are not well documented, too. So tests are needed by the OP.

Comment: @MenoHochschild @Hugo the solution was as you guys proposed, ```dtf.parseLocalDateTime(sendDate).toDate(DateTimeZone.UTC.toT‌​imeZone())```

The documentation are a bit ambiguous. I wasted quite some time on this

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specify a timezone for the toDate() method.

`dtf.parseLocalDateTime(sendDate).toDate(DateTimeZone.UTC.toT‌​‌​imeZone())`